# Screenshot Override Issue and Failed Folder Storage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've gotten the screenshot function to work on the simplest level. However, as soon as I try to append a folder to it or assign a directory, it fails to store every time. I've searched for a solution for months. I ended up trying so many things, I finally went back to basics and have ended up here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class BasicScreenShot: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string title="screencap";
    public int count=0;
    public void CapScrn() 
    {
        Application.CaptureScreenshot(title + count++ + ".png");
    }
}
```

This works, but it saves over itself every time I start the game again. I'd also like to add a folder destination for it to save to, but I can't get that to work either. I've tried `Directory.createDirectory` and that doesn't work. I tried `Application.dataPath + "/.../.../"` and that didn't work - even with `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Think of this: every single time you start the application, you will be doing this: `Application.CaptureScreenshot("screencap0.png")`. You need to store the last `count` value and retrieve it on application startup before calling `CapScrn`

Comment: Also, you should post all (or the most relevant) attempts so we can tell you why they didn't work as you coded them

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html), specifically the GetInt and SetInt methods

Comment: How do I store the last count? Also, I can't seem to add the code sections from my previous attempts. It says they're too long.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll read it straight away. Still can't get those code sections to paste here... I just signed up today. It's all very humbling!

Comment: The code samples need to be short enough, the more specific the better

Comment: Failure One:
public bool activateCapture = false;
public int screenshotCount = 0;
public string screenshotName = "Generated Character";
private string screenshotFile;
public void CaptureDef()
    {if (activateCapture == true)
        {
            string screenshotFile;
            do
            {
                screenshotCount++;
                screenshotFile = screenshotName + screenshotCount + ".png";
            } while (System.IO.File.Exists(screenshotFile));}
      Application.CaptureScreenshot(screenshotFile);}
public void Capture(){
        activateCapture = true;}

Comment: Here's the other failed one: 
public static string screenshotFolder = "/Character Inspirations/";

    public static string screenshotName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");

   public string CapturedFile;

  public void Start()
  {
      CapturedFile = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, screenshotFolder + screenshotName + ".png");
   }

 
public void Capture()
 {
     Application.CaptureScreenshot(CapturedFile);
   }

Comment: I recently tried the System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss") for the name in my most recent attempt, but it failed as well. I read that it has to do with regional time stamps or something like that. Is there a way to get that to work?

Comment: Sorry! I hadn't reloaded the page and I didn't know that the answer was posted. *feeling ultra n00bish* >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first time you call this function will use 0 as count, so you could do something like this to ensure the latest value is always used:

```
public class BasicScreenShot: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string title="screencap";
    public int count;

    public BasicScreenShot()
    {
        // this gets the last value stored on the device
        count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("screencapCount");
    }

    public void CapScrn() 
    {
        count++;
        Application.CaptureScreenshot(title + count + ".png");
        // ensure this value is saved onto the device
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("screencapCount", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! I haven't seen that before. I thought I'd have to set up a coroutine or something. What about adding a folder location?

Comment: It's saying that GetInt is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead.

Comment: Okay! I changed it to Awake from BasicScreenShot and it's working. Still can't get the folder to work though.

Comment: @CynthiaBreheny you should ask another question for the Folder subject ;)

Comment: Will do after more research! Thank you!